# Create a pandas dataframe with null columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having a hard time figuring this out. I am working on a program to keep track of some data associated with a bunch of files. I am using pandas to manage the data and load/save it. For the first run, the program identifies the files with the extension, and creates a pandas dataframe with some number of columns for the data associated with each file. The number of columns and the number of rows isn't known until runtime. I want to add all the file paths to a column, but leave all other columns blank for the DataFrame, is there a good way to do this? So if the input is `[val1, val2, val3,...]` then I want the DataFrame to be

```
[col1, col2, col,...,coln]
[val1, NaN, NaN,...,  NaN]
[val2, NaN, NaN,...,  NaN]
[val3, NaN, NaN,...,  NaN]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your dataframe from a dict, any extra columns specified in the `columns` keyword will be initialized as null:

```
In [3]: pd.DataFrame({'col1':['val1','val2','val3']}, 
                     columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
Out[3]:
   col1 col2 col3
0  val1  NaN  NaN
1  val2  NaN  NaN
2  val3  NaN  NaN
```

Alternatively if your first column is an index, you can use this syntax:

```
In [4]: pd.DataFrame([], ['val1','val2','val3'], ['col1','col2','col3'])
Out[4]:
     col1 col2 col3
val1  NaN  NaN  NaN
val2  NaN  NaN  NaN
val3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick reply!